# Is there any direct method (except URL) for Reverse geocoding by place id in android?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to get Google Address by Reverse Geocoding by placeId not by LatLng.

Though I found its web-service -https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

but in android, Geocoder does not have any function which can give me address by accepting placeId. I am using 10.0.1 version of google play services location library.

Comment: It is there `Reverse Geocoding for a Place ID` with url that url has to call using webservice(api) and you can get address in response.

Comment: This is what I am saying, they have provided webservice but not added in google play services library for android as they are providing for latlng.

Comment: May be this link guides you more : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests

Comment: this is again api calling from web which needs mapping of json to address class if implemented in android and it seems to be difficult if you see the json response.

Comment: You have difficulty with json. It's easy.

Comment: Its not that easy, json response have address_components->types and Android GeoCoder Class "Address" is very different. But I still was looking the way if google play service could provide.

Answer (score -1):

You can get all the details about a place by using place_id with below api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

put your place_id and Api_key and you will get the result

Comment: but how to use it in android?

Comment: Just try to access this url using Asynctask you will get a json response parse it

Comment: Isn't there any way to use it from Google Play Services in android like reverse geocoding by latlng is done by GeoCoder.getFromLocation(latlng).

Comment: No Geocoder doesn't have any method that takes placeid

Comment: I think they must add it in Geocoder if they have provided web-service.